# Flutter - Can I use one google map api key for iOS, android and place autocomplete?

Tags: flutter, google-maps

Do we have to use different google map API keys for each iOS, android, and place autocomplete?

currently, I am using one API key for all like this

[image]

and something is not working. the map suggests me the name of the locations when I type in the search text field, but I get the error when I tap on the name of the location. the error says

> Unhandled Exception: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in typecast

I think I am doing something wrong with the API keys.
Do we have to use different keys for each platform?

here is my http request

```
Future<String> getPlaceId(String input) async {
    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?input=$input&inputtype=textquery&key=$autocompletekey';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var placeId = json['candidates'][0]['place_id'] as String;
    print(placeId);
    return placeId;
  }

  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getPlace(String input) async {
    final placeId = await getPlaceId(input);
    final String url =
        'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/findplacefromtext/json?place_id=$placeId&key=$autocompletekey';
    final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
    var json = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    var results = json['result'] as Map<String, dynamic>; // this line of code produces error
    print(results);
    return results;
  }
```

Comment: Can you add some code, like http request method or exception stacktree etc.

Comment: hello @SalihCan Thanks for your reply. I have added some code to my question. Please have a look

Comment: Thank you, which line gives this error? Could you also add the error stacktree?

Comment: Here is the erro https://paste.pics/d843c2b0e194238d3d8875353f62a343

Comment: If you plan to restrict your API keys with application restrictions, it is recommended to use separate API keys as per: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Comment: @SawThaWah Did you try to console with 'print' the contents of the json variable on line 83? According to the error, there is no 'result' key in the response from the service